# assign variable to itself on declaration

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is self-initialization 'A a = a;' allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981714/is-self-initialization-a-a-a-allowed)

Consider the following code:

```
int main()
{
  int x = x;
  return 0;
}
```

Does it compile? Well, I thought it wouldn't, but it does according to my *gcc-4.2.1*. The value is unspecified, as it simply would state `int x;`.

It has some non-trivial consequences though, for example:

```
int x = 44;
int main()
{
  int x = x;
  return 0;
}
```

The `x` in `main` is still unspecified, as the third `x` is the second (I know I can overcome it by using `::x`, but it's not the point).

One can argue `int x = x;` in this case is equivalent to `int x; x = x;`, but things are getting more complicated when using a proper object:

```
class S
{
public:
  S(): x(44) { std::cout << "constructor" << std::endl; }  
  S(const S &s): x(s.x) 
             { std::cout << "copy " << this << " " << &s << std::endl; }

   int getx () const { return x; }

private:
  int x;  
};

int main()
{
  S s(s);
  std::cout << s.getx() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The code above prints:

```
copy 0x7fff65ac1598 0x7fff65ac1598
0
```

So obviously object passed to copy constructor is an unconstructed bag of garbage (which is not surprising if able to compile).

I don't get any warnings while compiling, even when using `-Wall -Wextra`. Is it a bug in *gcc*, completely valid behaviour or kind of a grey area?

(One way or another, it's really pain to debug.)

Comment: Just so you're sure, `Type type = something;` and `Type type; type = something;` are not the same.

Comment: @chris, sure, it's not, I probably shouldn't have been including this line into my question...

Comment: +1 A well worded/formatted question, even if it is a dup.

Comment: oh dear, I knew it must be something on SO, but couldn't find it. `self-initialization` was the keyword!

Comment: Try passing `-Wuninitialized` when compiling and see if that helps.

Comment: @JesseGood, nope, unfortunately it doesn't help.

Comment: It seems gcc will not give any warnings. One option would be to compile the code with a different compiler if that's possible.

Comment: @Jesse: You need both `-Wuininitialized` and `-Winit-self` to make GCC warn for this. `-Wuninitialized` is part of `-Wall` and `-Wextra`, but `-Winit-self` is not. Depending on GCC version, you may also need at least `-O1` before `-Wuninitialized` does anything, because the warning relies on the optimizer's data-flow analysis. I don't know exactly what versions require what optimization level, the man page just says it varies.

Comment: @SteveJessop: With built-in types it works, but with the example with `S s(s);` in the question, I could not produce a warning no matter what I did (using gcc 4.7.0) (although using [clang online](http://llvm.org/demo/) for example gives a warning).