# Object that initializes to itself in C++

Tags: c++, class, object, initialization, self

For example, I've the code:

```
class test{
    public:

    test(){
        cout<<endl<<"TEST";
    }

    void another(){
        cout<<endl<<"Another";
    }

};

int main(){
    test chk = chk;
    chk.another();
}
```

Here, I've done an initialization of newly created object of type `test` to itself.

Does such initialization serve special purpose, does such initialization do anything otherwise than initializing `test chk;` instead of `test chk = chk;`?

I understand that the constructor cannot be called if the object is initialized to itself, but why?

I would like to know more about such initialization of an object to itself.

Comment: Initializing your object that way means calling a copy constructor but you have already declared a constructor so the compiler will not implicittlly define one. and assuming that you did not define your constructor ,implict  copy constructor will copy object member by member and this will not work because chk does exist yet in the memory

Comment: @AnisBelaid You have that the wrong way round. Declaring an explicit copy constructor would prevent a default constructor being implicitly declared, not the other way round. This class does get an implicit copy constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified your code a bit and hope you can catch the point:

```
class test{
    public:
        test(){ cout<<endl<<"TEST"; }

        test(const test& in)
        {   
            if ( this == &in)
            {   
                cout<<endl<<"Self init";
            }
            cout<<endl<<"Copy ctor";
        }

        void another(){ cout<<endl<<"Another"; }
};  

int main(){
    test chk = chk;
    chk.another();
    cout<<endl;
}
```

If you now call your code you will get the following output:

```
Self init
Copy ctor
Another
```

One remark to your `cout<<endl` statements. You last output are hidden because there is no `endl` after the last output. `cout` is buffered which means here that it will only write to your console after the next `endl` or the buffer is full. So it is even better to write: `cout<<"something"<<endl;`

To the code and the init:

If you take the address of the input object in your copy constructor you can check if you do a copy to yourself. That is good practice, because you need a own copy constructor if you have allocated memory which can't be copied with the default constructor. As you can see from my example, the address of `this` and `in` is the same which means the copy constructor want to copy to itself which is typically wrong if not handled in a special way!

For your testcase the behaviour is simply that your object is not initialized, because you copy an uninitialzed object to itself which ends up in a uninitialized object. This is never what you want and clang reports a warning.

Answer (score 6):

You are allowed to write:

```
test chk = chk;
```

*[basic.scope.declarative]/p1*

> The potential scope of the first `j` begins immediately after that `j`

An [implicit copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) is thus invoked. You might have used your own to perform some additional initialization:

```
test(const test&) {
  cout << endl << "copy ctor";
}
```

Keep in mind that this isn't a good practice and it might even lead to [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/981714/1938163) under some circumstances and Clang always issues a `-Wuninitialized` warning.

Comment: Now I understand that a copy constructor is called , However, why don't I " see it working? " , What i mean is , the cout doesn't output the message in the console window.

Comment: @zLeon do you mean [like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78b4a64deed709dd)? Not sure I understand this last issue

Comment: What I mean is , if the constructor wasen't taking any object as a reference, but it would be just test(){ cout<<endl<<"copy ctor "; } , why wouldn't it work?

Comment: Because that isn't a valid signature for a copy constructor

Comment: You'd be calling copy-constructor on an object that has not yet been constructed however