# Why does object initializatized with itself work without errors?

Tags: c++, initialization

In the below example, I initialize `obj` with itself.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class base {
public:
    base()
    {
        std::cout << "base" << std::endl;
    }

    base(const base& obj)
    {
        std::cout << "copy base" << std::endl;
    }

};

int main ()
{
    base obj = obj;
}
```

This program prints "copy base".
Why default constructor isn't called?
Why there is no error?
Why is it allowed?

Comment: Why would you do this?  You are trying to initialize a new object with itself.  Surely this is undefined behavior.

Comment: You could call `base::base()` from `base::base(const base &)` with a _delegating constructor_.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/308318/1563833).

Comment: What is obj? Does this code compile?

Comment: This code shouldn't even compile. Please share the shortest working example. But the default constructor gets called if you do the following base obj;

Comment: @ItumelengTlali `obj` is a `base`, and the definition of `base` is right above `main`. It compiles if you add `#include <iostream>`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object that initializes to itself in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759210/object-that-initializes-to-itself-in-c) (see the second answer)

Comment: ... and some `std::*`, sandeep please provide a [mre], with the emphasis on "reproducible".  We should be able to copy-paste your code and run it without further modifications.