# Why this code segment could be compiled? With undeclared variable `PWL`？

Tags: c++

```cpp
int func(int a) {
    int PWL = PWL;
    return PWL;
}

int main() {
    return func(1);
}
```

Please see the godbolt:
link
https://godbolt.org/z/1c1Kax18n

Comment: May answer your question [Object that initializes to itself in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759210/object-that-initializes-to-itself-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

`int PWL = PWL;` does declare `PWL`. Though it is using the value of `PWL` before it is initialized, hence causes undefined behavior.

Sometimes such self referential initialization is desired, for example:

```
 void* ptr = &ptr;
```

This is completely fine. Your case is not. Compilers should warn about it. See here for how it does not compile once you enable warnings: https://godbolt.org/z/vM7KMbfvv.