# How this line is working in this C++ code?

Tags: c++, reference, operators

I was testing how the deference between the dot member selection operator and the arrow member selection operator (.) and (->).
but i don't understand how when I put the reference equaling to itself. it works. and if i deleted any of the two lines above it. it gives me error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class count
{
public:
   void setX(int value)
   {
      x=value;
   }
   void printX()
   {
      cout<<x<<endl;
   }
private:
   int x;
};
int main()
{
   count counter;
   count *counterPtr=&counter;
   count &counterRef=counterRef; // here! I mistakenly put the
                                 //to reference to itself. but it 
                                 //works fine.

   counter.setX(7);
   counter.printX();

   counterRef.setX(8);           
   counterRef.printX();     //it works fine as and prints the value

   (*counterPtr).setX(9);
   (*counterPtr).printX();

   counterPtr->setX(10);
   counterPtr->printX();
}
```

Comment: the question is more likely to be about how the reference line works more than the class or the (.) and (->) operators. why didn't it give me error when i initialized it to itself. i mean the reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is self-initialization 'A a = a;' allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981714/is-self-initialization-a-a-a-allowed)

Comment: The compiler will let you know you're doing something wonky (and it also gives you a term to search for): https://godbolt.org/g/tN56sk  "<source>:21:11: warning: reference 'counterRef' is initialized with itself [-Winit-self]
"

Comment: @xaxxon thank you. but i'm not sure i could understand from the duplicated question. the line `count &counterRef=counterRef;` creates a reference to an object of type `count`. what i could understand is that it's illegal? so why it worked on my compiler? and thank you.

Comment: You may be horrified to find that there are a great many really bad ideas logically that are syntactically correct and compile. This appears to be one of them. I get a *warning: 'counterRef' is used uninitialized in this function* from my trusty old friend the compiler and because I have Warnings as Errors turned on, this won't compile for me. Check with your doctor to see if Warnings as Errors is right for you.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/zc8YWX  You can see that it's never actually constructing an object.  Since a reference is simply a pointer under the covers, it's most likely creating an uninitialized reference pointing to undefined memory which is UB and may appear to "work" at times.  What I'm seeing here is that the address is 0x0: https://wandbox.org/permlink/z6uAvtSAibAcJcaL but not sure why or if that's somehow guaranteed or not.